# Unity Line Renderer Wont follow raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

Cant get the line renderer to follow the raycast? 
Here is the raycast code as well as the bullet trail code. The line render shoots out as it is supposed to, however it just goes in a straight line in front of the player and not where the player clicks/raycast shoots out.

```
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
public float fireRate = 0;
public float Damage = 0;
public LayerMask whatToHit;

public Transform BulletTrailPrefab;

float timeToFire = 0;
Transform firePoint;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Awake() {
    firePoint = transform.Find("FirePoint");
    if (firePoint == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No Firepoint?");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (fireRate == 0)
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Shoot();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > timeToFire)
        {
            timeToFire = Time.time + 1/fireRate;
            Shoot();
        }
    }
}
    void Shoot()        { 

        Vector2 mousePosition = new Vector2(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).x, Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition).y);
        Vector2 firePointPosition = new Vector2(firePoint.position.x, firePoint.position.y);
        RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPosition, mousePosition-firePointPosition, 100, whatToHit);
        Effect();
        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, (mousePosition - firePointPosition)*100, Color.cyan);
        if (hit.collider != null)
        {
            Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.name + "and did" + Damage + "Damage");
        }
    }
    void Effect()
{
    Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation); 
}
}
```

and the bullet trail:

```
public class Trail : MonoBehaviour
{
public int moveSpeed = 20;

 // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    Destroy(GameObject, 1);
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: does it work for the `Debug.DrawLine` and is `firePoint` rotated according to the mouse position?

Comment: @derHugo Yes, the line can be seen in scene view but for some reason the line renderer just shoots in a straight line in front of the player, debug shows the raycast is hitting the object the mouse is pointed to

Comment: yes but the main issue is that you never actually rotate the `firePoint` towards the mouse => it will always have its default rotation => `transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);` will always move in world right direction (only on the X axis) since it doesn't take the mouse direction into account

Comment: @derHugo Oh okay thanks, how would i change the code to make it do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: Your issue is that you are not rotating `firePoint` to point towards the mouse position.

Therefore using

```
Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
```

will probably equal

```
Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

and therefore

```
transform.Translate (Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
```

always moves only in world X direction.

---

I would use a dedicated method to initialize the spawned object with requried information and also move the `Destroy` call there so it is done only once:

```
public class Trail : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int moveSpeed = 20;

    private Vector2 _direction;
    private bool _isInitialized;

    public void Initialize(Vector2 direction)
    {
        _direction = direction;
        _isInitialized = true;

        Destroy(gameObject, 1);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(!_isInitialized) return;

        transform.Translate (_direction * Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
    }
}
```

and then use it like

```
// Use the correct type here
public Trail BulletTrailPrefab;

private void Shoot()        
{ 
    Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Vector2 firePointPosition = firePoint.position;
    var direction = (mousePosition-firePointPosition).normalized;
    var hit = Physics2D.Raycast(firePointPosition, direction, 100, whatToHit);

    // no pass in the direction
    Effect(direction);

    Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, direction * 100, Color.cyan);

    if (hit.collider != null)
    {
        Debug.DrawLine(firePointPosition, hit.point, Color.red);
        Debug.Log("Hit " + hit.collider.name + "and did" + Damage + "Damage");
    }
}

private void Effect(Vector2 direction)
{
    var bullet = Instantiate(BulletTrailPrefab, firePoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
    bullet.Initialize(direction);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that looks great i am getting a Error CS0103 The name 'origin' does not exist in the current context. What should this be?

Comment: Was a typo .. try now